# Migrate AngularJS to Angular 8

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope

i need to put this code line (angularJS) in angular 2+ , how can i do this?

I already do some searchs but this line is confusing me.

scope.variable.value = event.color.toHex()

**Old Code:**

```
function callColorpicker() {
    var colorpicker = $('.colorpicker')
    colorpicker.colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(event) {
      
      var scope = angular.element(this).scope()
      scope.variable.value = event.color.toHex()

      if ($scope.autoapplysass) {
        $scope.autoApplySass()
      }
    })
  }
```

**New Code:**

```
callColorpicker() {
      var colorpicker = $('.colorpicker')
      colorpicker.colorpicker();
      var _this = this;
      colorpicker.colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(event) {
      
      --> scope.variable.value = event.color.toHex()

          if (_this.applySass) {
            _this.applySass(false)
          }
      })     
    }
```

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: can you add a snippet of your code and show what exactly you wanna change?

Comment: already added now

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can avoid jQuery with Angular it's a good thing because Angular handles things completely differently than JQ and in many ways the two step on each other's toes. This can be difficult to troubleshoot and down the line could cause issues that are increasingly harder to diagnose.

In your case, as luck would have it, there is an angular color picker component you could substitute with.

- NPMJS page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker
- Demo: https://zefoy.github.io/ngx-color-picker/
- StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/zefoy/ngx-color-picker/tree/master

install with npm `npm install ngx-color-picker --save`

Then in `app.module.ts`

```
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    ColorPickerModule
  ]
})
```

In your HTML

```
<input [(colorPicker)]="color" 
        [style.background]="color"
        (colorPickerChange)="onColorChange($event)"   />
```

and in your component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorPickerService, Cmyk } from 'ngx-color-picker';

constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private cpService: ColorPickerService) {}

export class AppComponent {
    color: string;

    onColorChange(newColor) {
       
          this.color = newColor;

          if (_this.applySass) {
            _this.applySass(false)
          }
       
    }
```